# Procedimiento Almacenado desde s3

Tags: sql, aws, amazon-s3

AL momento de subir archivos .txt a S3 quiero utilizarlos para hacer un Stored Procedure. ¿Esto es posible? ya que a la hora de mandar el parámetro para el store procedure me da error.
Adjunto stored procedure con parámetro de ejemplo:

```
EXEC  SPI_Archivos 'https://elasticbeanstal.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/o.txt'


  
CREATE  PROCEDURE SPI_Archivos                 
@filePath varchar(max)                      
AS                       
BEGIN                
  SET LANGUAGE Spanish;                
            
  CREATE TABLE #TempTable (                
    Cuenta nvarchar(max),                
    Nombre nvarchar(max),                
    Monto float,                
    Fecha DATETIME,                
    Clasificación nvarchar(max))                
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'BULK INSERT #TempTable FROM ''' + @filePath + ''' WITH (CODEPAGE = ''ACP'',FIRSTROW=2, ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';                       
  EXEC (@sql);                
                
  Insert into Balanzas              
  select * from(              
  select Cuenta,Nombre,Monto,Fecha,Clasificación from #TempTable              
  except               
  SELECT Cuenta,Nombre,Monto,Fecha,Clasificación  from Balanzas) p              
  END
```

Y este es el error que me genera:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> No se puede realizar la carga masiva. El archivo 'https://elasticbeaalk-us-east-2-318.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/o.txt'
> no se puede abrir. Código de error del sistema operativo: 86(La
> contraseña de red especificada no es válida.).

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el error que te da

Comment: @AlfaRojo Acabo de Actualizar la pregunta con el error que me genera